# Improve performance of Recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, query-performance, recursive-query

I have a pretty simple recursive CTE running on a single sourcetable (`REP.INVENTMOVEMENTS`) containing around 4mln records. The table is pretty heavily indexed.

```
with 
dataset as (
    select imv.sourceBatch, 
           imv.targetBatch,
           imv.sourceDataArea, 
           imv.targetDataArea,
           sum(Weight) as Weight
    from REP.INVENTMOVEMENTS imv 
    where imv.sourceBatch <> ''
    Group By imv.sourceBatch, 
             imv.targetBatch,
             imv.sourceDataArea, 
             imv.targetDataArea
    ),
result as (
    select  targetBatch as Batch,
            targetDataArea as DataArea, 
            sourceBatch, 
            targetBatch,   
            sourceDataArea,
            targetDataArea, 
            1 as level,
            Weight
    from dataset
    where sourceBatch <> targetBatch

    union all 

    select result.Batch,
           result.DataArea, 
           dataset.sourceBatch, 
           dataset.targetBatch, 
           dataset.sourceDataArea,
           dataset.targetDataArea, 
           result.level + 1 as level,
           dataset.Weight
    from dataset inner join result on dataset.targetBatch       = result.sourceBatch 
                                  and dataset.targetDataArea    = result.sourceDataArea
                                  and dataset.targetBatch       <> dataset.sourceBatch
    )

select * from result
union all
select      targetBatch as Batch,
            targetDataArea as DataArea, 
            sourceBatch, 
            targetBatch,   
            sourceDataArea,
            targetDataArea, 
            0 as level,
            Weight
    from dataset
    where sourceBatch = targetBatch
;
```

running the initial query without selections takes the database 122 seconds returning 517.947 records.

Running that same query returning a single batch takes the database less then a second returning 5 records.

But if I run the CTE with a selection on 1 batch it takes the database 28 seconds to complete 2 recursions and return 7 records.

I need to fill a table with the result from this view for 150k batches. so if all of them take half a minute to complete it would take 52 days to finish that task.

This is the execution plan

[Executionplan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBRMv.png)

Just to clarify my objective. Batches can merge into new batches so 2 or more source batches can create an new batch. Two batches created in such a merge can be used to create a new batch... and so forth.

I want to be able to select a batch and find all the batches used to create this new batch.

Please take into account that one batch can be used in multiple other batches.

I hope you can help me out here.

Comment: could you give some example data? with the indexes you have on the tables, how many batches do you have?

Comment: Without looking at the execution plan, or any indexes on tables, purely the construction with the first CTE and then the recursive CTE: I would populate the first CTE to a temporary tables (appropriately indexed if needed) in a prior statement, then use that temporary table in the recursive CTE. Do note that recursive CTEs aren't known for their good performance. They usually don't fare well on large datasets.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the issue by creating an internal table and filling that with the dataset needed to execute the recursive query.

```
DECLARE @BatchSequence as table(Batch           nvarchar(100),
                                SourceBatch nvarchar(100),
                                TargetBatch nvarchar(100),
                                Weight          decimal(18,3));

insert into @BatchSequence 
select ReportingBatch, SourceBatch,TargetBatch, SUM(Weight) as Weight
from REP.INVENTMOVEMENTS
WHERE sourceBatch <> ''
Group By ReportingBatch, SourceBatch,TargetBatch;

with 
result as (
    select  targetBatch as Batch,
            sourceBatch, 
            targetBatch,   
            1 as level,
            Weight
    from @BatchSequence dataset
    where sourceBatch <> targetBatch

    union all 

    select result.Batch,
           dataset.sourceBatch, 
           dataset.targetBatch, 
           result.level + 1 as level,
           dataset.Weight
    from @BatchSequence dataset inner join result on dataset.targetBatch        = result.sourceBatch 
                                  and dataset.targetBatch       <> dataset.sourceBatch
    )
```

This returns 250k records in 1 minute.

Hope this can help someone else.