# Grouping shift data by 7-day windows in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, recursive-query

What I want to do is to calculate the number of shifts and hours worked by each employee in any given 7-day period. In order to achieve this, I need to identify and group 'islands' of shifts.  Note that this 7-day period is not tied to a calendar week and the beginning and ending of this 7-day period would vary from employee to employee. This is sets it apart from other similar questions asked her in the past.

I have a table like this:

```
Person ID   Start Date  End Date    Start time      End time    Hours Worked
12345       06-07-20    06-07-20    6:00 AM         7:45 AM     1.75
12345       06-07-20    06-07-20    8:15 AM         8:45 AM     0.50
12345       06-07-20    06-07-20    9:19 AM         9:43 AM     0.40
12345       08-07-20    08-07-20    12:00 AM        12:39 AM    0.65
12345       09-07-20    09-07-20    10:05 PM        11:59 PM    1.90
12345       11-07-20    11-07-20    4:39 PM         4:54 PM     0.25
12345       22-07-20    22-07-20    7:00 AM         7:30 AM     0.50
12345       23-07-20    23-07-20    1:00 PM         3:00 PM     2.00
12345       24-07-20    24-07-20    9:14 AM         9:35 AM     0.35
12345       27-07-20    27-07-20    4:00 PM         6:00 PM     2.00
12345       27-07-20    27-07-20    2:00 PM         4:00 PM     2.00
12345       28-07-20    28-07-20    9:00 AM         10:00 AM    1.00
12345       28-07-20    28-07-20    4:39 AM         4:59 AM     0.34
```

I want group and summarise the data above like this:

```
Person ID   From        To          Number of shifts    Number of Hours
12345       06-07-20    11-07-20    6                   5.45
12345       22-07-20    28-07-20    7                   8.19
```

Note that the first grouping for employee `12345` starts on `06-07-20` and ends on `11-07-20` because these shifts fall within the `06-07-20` - `13-07-20` 7-day window.

The next day 7-day window is from `22-07-20` to `28-07-20`, which means that the start date for the 7-day window has to be dynamic and based on the data i.e. not constant which makes this a complex task.

Also note that an employee may work multiple shifts in a day and that the shifts may not be consecutive.

I was playing around with using `DATEDIFF()` with `LAG()` and `LEAD()` but was unable to get to where I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 6th July was a Monday. Does that matter? Are there any other criteria than just the first date (or the date being a Monday) that would start a 7-day period?

Comment: Seems `Start / End time` is varchar value.... Am i right?

Comment: Also `Start/End Date` seems to be varchar data type... This causes the need of data conversion which may be the reason of slow performance.

Comment: @marcothesane there is no real criteria for the start of a 7-day period i.e. it does not matter what day of the week it is.

Comment: @MaciejLos Start time and End time are TIME values. Start date and End date are DATE values.

Comment: Sorry, but i doubt. Date data type is using four digits for year. Can you share your table definition (structure)?

Comment: So just a "gap" of 1 day and more between a period and the next marks the differences? Or do I also have to break a possible series of 14 consecutive days into 7-day chunks? Your data has two "islands": 6th July to 11th July , and 22 July to 28th July. What if it were 22th July to 31st July, or  4th/5th August, for that matter?

Comment: @MaciejLos I just write it that way for readability. Here's the table structure:

```CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shift Logs](
 [Person ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Start Date] [date] NULL,
 [End Date] [date] NULL,
 [Start time] [time](7) NULL,
 [End time] [time](7) NULL,
 [Hours Worked] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO```

Comment: @marcothesane There are two 'islands' in my example, yes. Islands can have any number of records as long as it is a 7-day window. For example, if this employee had also worked on `14-07-2020` then that would be an island in itself. If they had worked on `15-07-2020` instead, then the grouping would include 2 shifts, the one they worked on `15-07-2020` and the one on `22-07-2020`. The remaining records would be in a separate grouping. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: In that case, every subsequent 7-day group depends on either a gap in the data or the shape of the preceding 7-day group. This can't be done without a recursion, so follow @GMB' s advice ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a recursive CTE gor this. The idea is to enumerate the shifts of each person, and then iteratively walk the dataset, while keeping track of the first date of the period - when there is more than 7 days between the start of a period and the current date, the start date resets, and a new group starts.

```
with recursive 
    data as (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by personid order by start_date) rn from mytable t)
    cte as (
        select personid, start_date, start_date end_date, hours_worked, rn 
        from data 
        where rn = 1
        union all
        select 
            c.personid, 
            case when d.start_date > dateadd(day, 7, c.start_date) then d.start_date else c.start_date end,
            d.start_date,
            d.hours_worked,
            d.rn
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.personid = c.personid and d.rn = c.rn + 1
    )
select personid, start_date, max(start_date) end_date, count(*) no_shifts, sum(hours_worked)
from cte
group by personid, start_date
```

This assumes that:

- dates do not span over multiple days, as shown in your sample data
- dates are stored as `date` datatype, and times as `time`

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I just have a follow-up because I'm not familiar with recursive CTEs. I'm getting an `Invalid column name 'rn'` error on line 14. Any idea why? Highly appreciate it.

Comment: @ashvin10: my bad, this column has to go the `select` clause too. Fixed.

Comment: Ran into this error while running it on the full data set: `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.` Any ideas on how to over some this limitation, @GMB?

Comment: @ashvin10: you can add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

Comment: Thanks for that fix, it seemed to have done the trick. However, the dataset that I am running this on has over 1 million rows of data and as a result, the code you suggested has been running over 5 hours now (and it has yet to finish). Just wondering if you had any ideas on how to improve the performance. Would highly appreciate it :)

Comment: Actually, figured that out myself, @GMB. For anyone else who is curious, I followed @DanielSander's recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017270/improve-performance-of-recursive-cte) and created a temp table with ROW_NUMBER column and then ran the recursive CTE on it, like so
`SELECT t.*
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Person ID] ORDER BY [Start Date]) AS rn 
INTO Attendance_Logs_with_RN
FROM Attendance Logs t
.
.
.
`